# Read the echo output of php file in python

Tags: php, python, backendless

I have a database on backendless cloud service which has no support for python.

So i'm establishing the connection between the python code and the database using php files.

The insertion is working fine as there is no response from the php file to the python.

However in the retrieving i need the php file to echo the output and the python script to read this echo value. How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your PHP files deployed as Server Code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subprocess` module to execute the PHP code from python.

Assuming that your PHP script write to standard output [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) would be the easiest, or you could use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) if you need better control of the child process.

If you are using Python >= 3.5 then you can use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Answer (score 0):

To read from stdout with python you can use subprocess module

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("ls",stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # in your case, "ls" change with php command
print p.communicate()  # here you will get ls output
```

But I don't think that this is a good solution to solve your problem. A better solution will be to use php as REST service. And then with python use it as REST.

```
import json
import urllib2
json.load(urllib2.urlopen("htt://yourphpapplicationaddress.com"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use pipe, for example:

```
php test.php | grep 'xxx' python text.python
```

that's it, python can get the echo data of php from sys.argv